# What parameters of a neural network should be changed when increasing the number of training samples?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, graph-neural-network

I was testing a DL model (GNN with two GCN layers and one linear layer) on a small dataset for a regression purpose, the resulted MAE and the scatter plot showed some really good results.
However, when I applied the same model for a 10x dataset, the results (especially the scatter plot) showed random with low range outputs.
With having the first training results that good and the second training that bad, I assumed that with increasing the number of subjects some parameters must be changed. Note that I have a high number of epochs with early stop (and the training is in both cases ended with early stop).
Any suggestions?